# Find this limit using L`Hopitals rule

Tags: calculus, limits

In Problems in Mathematical Analysis, Volume 2 by Kaczor and Nowak, Problem 2.3.34 is stated as follow.

Find this limit using L`Hôpital rule

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x((1+\frac{1}{x})^x-e).$$

I have tried by using L'Hospital rule five times but have no result.  I can compute this limit by using Taylor expansion.

Comment: Did you write it as $((1+1/x)^x - e)/(1/x)$? Applying l'Hop once to that should get you where you need to go.

Comment: yes, I did. But it seems more complicated.

Comment: Write out your derivative for the numerator and denominator

Comment: I agree with @Simon S. Except in trivial cases, it is in fact almost never simpler to use L'Hopital's rule than to use perturbation expansions, *if* you now what you are doing with the expansions.

Comment: It's upperbounded by 0 and monotone increasing. The limit should be 0.

Comment: @SimonS: $$\frac{e^{x\ln(1+1/x)}(\ln(1+1/x)+\frac{x}{1+1/x}.\frac{-1}{x^2})}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$$

Comment: @Alex: The answer is $-\frac{e}{2}$.

Comment: Ok. Now cancel out the $1/x^2$. One term $(1+1/x)^x \to e$. You're left to find the limit of the other term. And you'll need l'Hop again, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change the limit into this form,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}{x}.$$

and apply L`Hôpital rule to get,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \;(x+1)^{1/x} \frac{\left(\frac{x}{x+1}-\log (x+1)\right)}{x^2}.$$

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \;(x+1)^{1/x} =e$ , you may want to know if $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(\frac{x}{x+1}-\log (x+1)\right)}{x^2}$  exist. Apply L`Hôpital rule again,
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(\frac{x}{x+1}-\log (x+1)\right)}{x^2} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{-1}{2 (x+1)^2} = -\frac{1}{2}$$

It exist and we are done,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \;(x+1)^{1/x} \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(\frac{x}{x+1}-\log (x+1)\right)}{x^2} = -\frac{e}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use L'Hopital Rule and substitution to get the answer. In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left[(1+\frac 1x)^x-e\right]&=&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac 1x)^x-e}{\frac 1x} \quad (\text{let } u=\frac 1x)\\
&=&\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{(1+u)^{\frac{1}{u}}-e}{u}\\
&=&\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{u}\ln(1+u)}-e}{u}\\
&=&\lim_{u\to 0}e(\frac{1}{u}\ln(1+u))'\\
&=&-\frac{e}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}
Here we use $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$ to compute
$$ \lim_{u\to 0}(\frac{1}{u}\ln(1+u))'=-\frac 12. $$